# É correto perguntar-se a um motorista se "passa ao Palácio?"?

Tags: gramática

É normal perguntar-se a um motorista de autocarro, quando queremos saber se aquele autocarro passa num determinado sítio:

- `Passa ao Palácio [de Cristal]?`
- `Passa ao Marquês?`
- `Passa aos Aliados?`
- `Passa à Rotunda?`

Isto é correto? Porquê?
Não seria mais correto dizer "passa **no** Palácio" ou "passa **pelo** Palácio"?

Será um regionalismo do norte de Portugal?

Comment: Mas onde é que isso se diz assim? Eu diria *passei no/pelo palácio* se entrasse lá dentro; *passei junto ao/ao pé do palácio* se não chegasse a entrar.

Comment: Uma eilpse? "Passa (em frente) ao Palácio?"

Comment: Aqui no Brasil, se perguntarem isso, ninguém entende  a pergunta.

Comment: Pode dizer-se _passar ao lado/largo/pé (de qualquer coisa)_, mas isso não tem que ver com _passar_: _está ao lado/largo/pé_. Eu também não me lembro de ouvir coisas como _passa ao palácio_.

Comment: Onde é que se fala dessa forma?  Aqui no Brasil dizemos "no", "na", ou "pelo"  Ou ainda, com o significado um pouco diferente, "próximo ao", "perto do".

Comment: Clarifiquei. Fora do contexto de perguntar a um motorista, de facto, nem para mim faz sentido.

Comment: @bfavaretto  Entendem sim.   Exemplo: Passa ao aeroporto de Congonhas?  Passa à Avenida Paulista?  O motorista achar esquisito mas vai entender.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Está correto, sim senhor. Estou pouco habituado a ouvir, e quando li a pergunta pela primeira vez, senti estranheza. Tenho a desculpa de a primeira versão da pergunta apresentar "passa ao palácio" sem contexto. Mas eis o que diz o Dicionário da Academia das Ciências de Lisboa:

> ***a*** *preposição* **A** Valores semânticos: **I.** Na expressão de valores locativos, indica: (...) **5** Localização, situação precisa ou aproximada. *Ela mora num palacete a São Bento [zona de Lisboa]. Pôs as cadeiras a todo o comprimento da sala.*

E eu ou já estou influenciado pela pergunta ou recordo-me mesmo de na minha infância ouvir coisas como:

> A camioneta (i.e. o autocarro, i.e. o ônibus) ***passa à*** Aldeia Grande?

E encontrei na net construções parecidas, mas só em Portugal:

> [***Passa à*** Praça do Comércio?](http://corta-fitas.blogs.sapo.pt/3792658.html) [Em Lisboa.]
>
> [[A era de ouro da aviação]](http://proximaviagem.com/estorias-minha-cidade/era-de-ouro-da-aviacao/) Ia-se a pé, sobretudo, às vezes no autocarro que ***passava ao*** Areeiro [praça de Lisboa, hoje chamada Dr. Sá Carneiro].
>
> [[Mãos ao Ar]](http://www.maosaoar.blogspot.pt/2007/02/uma-vnia-duas-vnias-as-vnias-que-ele.html) O [autocarro nº] 50 vai de Algés para a Gare do Oriente. Não ***passa ao*** Campo Grande.
>
> [[Homilia diária]](http://paroquiasfassis.blogspot.pt/2015_06_01_archive.html) Da mesma forma é Jesus quem ***passa à*** casa da sogra de Pedro, toca nela e a febre desaparece.
>
> [[17ª subida do Vale Sameiro, Serra da Estrela]](http://www.terrasdeaventura.net/desafio_run/sameiro/sameiro.htm) (…) a estrada florestal que ***passa à*** Fonte do Burro e Mata do Fragusto.
>
> [[Canto Alentejano]](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kWFyvqg-Stk#t=127) Ó Luar da meia noite, não digas à minha amada, que ***passei à*** rua dela, às quatro da madrugada.

E ninguém se lembra de [Não ***passes*** com ela ***à*** minha rua](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o0wLygwqLeo)? Com [letra aqui](http://www.vagalume.com.br/fernanda-maria/nao-passes-com-ela-a-minha-rua.html).

Encontrei *passar a* em livros antigos, mas significando *ir a/para*, indicando portanto a preposição ***a*** destino, o que é um uso mais habitual. Esta é também um interpretação possível de "é Jesus quem passa à casa da sogra" acima. Poderá estar aqui a origem do *passar à rua*, etc.:

> (...) Infantaria, que não querendo receber o Soldo, amotinada ***passou ao Sitio*** da Nazareth, onde elegêo Cabos e Officiais, conservando-se 3 dias sedicioza. [(J. C. Feo Cardozo de Castellobranco e Torres, *Memória*, 1825)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=FXpZAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA222&lpg=PA222&dq=%22passou%20ao%20s%C3%ADtio%22&source=bl&ots=2F57TCnOSi&sig=NyGkhT5Jra72Ym8lt9flww3gUCE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiq4rTj_tXJAhVIcBoKHRG0C4QQ6AEILjAD#v=onepage&q=%22passou%20ao%20s%C3%ADtio%22&f=false)

Comment: Ficaria mais contente com exemplos com "ao". "à" pode ser simplesmente erro ortográfico, já que "passa a Praça do Comércio" se diz com "a" aberto devido à contração do "a" final de "passa" com o artigo.

Comment: Encontrei uns exemplos com ***ao***, e uns exemplos antigos interessantes: *passar* pode no passado ter significado *ir a* ou *ir para*, como hoje podemos dizer, *já vimos a sala, passemos à cozinha*.